# A question about transformation between matrix spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_{m \times n}(R)$ a vector space includes all of the $m \times n$ matrices. Let $T:M_{m \times n}(R) \rightarrow M_{l \times n}(R) $ be a linear transformation. Is there always an $l \times m$ matrix $A$ such that $T(M)=AM$ for all $M \in M_{m \times n}(R) $?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (sort of clearly) false for $n>1$ because of dimension reasons: the space of linear maps $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{l\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $mln^2$, while the space of $(l\times m)$-matrices has only dimension $lm$. For $n=1$, it is not hard to see that the statement is true.

For a more explicit argument, we let $m=l=1$ and $n=2$, and ask ourselves if any linear map $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is just scalar multiplication. But rotation of the plane by $90^\circ$ shows that this is not true.

For a more explicit general argument, we can always find a linear map $T\colon M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{l\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ sending the matrix $E_{1,1}$ (that has a $1$ on entry $(1,1)$ and zeroes everywhere else) to an $(l\times n)$-matrix with $1$'s in all entries. However, if $n>1$, then for any $(l\times m)$-matrix $A$, the matrix $AE_{1,1}$ has all columns except the first one to be completely $0$, and therefore $AE_{1,1}$ cannot equal $T(E_{1,1})$ for any $(l\times m)$-matrix $A$ when $n>1$.